# Clicking a textView to get detailed data

Tags: ios

I am newer in iOS development.I got an email id of a person in textview then on click of this email id. I need to get information of email just like native mail in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to store or have information related to that email in your app. So when user would tap on your textview then you could check for condition that it should not be nil and email validation. As you have verified then you can fetch data from your app related to that email and show in a pop-up view.

Comment: Thanks Sir but when we import contact from address book information regarding email is present. Then i want to know for this we make new controller. or their is any default controller of  ABPersonViewController.

Comment: sorry but no idea about any defaulter controller related to this still if I came across anything related to your query will update you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have information for email or fetch anyhow.
You can use delegate methods and in **endediting** you can check for condition that it should not be nil and email validation.

Comment: but my question is that when email is one textview and one click this show all email of person

Comment: So you want the emailid linkable.

Comment: yes just like native mail when email id enter in to ,cc and then click